# Alternate approaches for Rendering UI from xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

In my project which is a legacy application , the html pages are rendered from xml. i.e the backend with pass the xml to the jsp and using xslt we generate the html content. Applying xslt on xml is done in browser using java script. The output of xslt will be a rich html content which will the view for user. And user can do edit actions like modifying values in form fields, adding dynamic items like new address lines etc. At the time of submit java script will read all the inputs (including dynamic user actions added a new row) and update the xml accordingly. Then this xml will be send back to backend and java code will parse the xml to see that user has modified and act accordingly.

I was thinking of alternate approach to build UI based on the input xml and with the facility to update xml in front end itself.

Any suggesstions on different approach?

Answer (score 0):

At my work some coworkers are using a very similar approach: The whole data is hold in a SQL-Database and got exported as XML. Further the XML got processed to XHTML via XSLT-Stylesheets to static pages. It is not intended that users edit content, so static HTML is absolutely fine.

In my case this make sense, in yours maybe not. Why you are not using the common [Web-Application-Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) approach?

If you really want to stay with your "XML->HTML with JS in browser"-solution try [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). It should make your life much easier (Model-Binding, Auto-Update, MVC-Pattern/Templating)

Comment: Thanks for the details. We cannot move out of xml because the entire clients (this is a hosted service) have their own xml formats.